# Concrete bases for functions on $S_n$

Tags: probability-theory, symmetric-groups

At the moment I am studying random walks on the symmetric group $S_n$, and have stumbled across the following problem, which seems to be concrete enough to might have a known answer, even though I cannot find one.

My problem is the following; I am studying the space of all functions on the symmetric group into $ \mathbb{R} $, and it is quite easy to find a set of functions whose span is this space, e.g. the functions $ \psi_{i,j}(\sigma) = 1_ {\sigma(i) = j}$. However, I would want to have such a set of functions which is orthogonal with respect to the inner product $\langle \psi_1, \psi_2 \rangle = \mathbb{E}[\psi_1(\sigma) \psi_2(\sigma)] $ where the underlying probability measure is the uniform measure on $S_n$, i.e. a basis for the space of all functions on $S_n$, given my inner product. Is any such baseis, where the base vectors can be explicitly described, known?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\mathbb{E}[\psi_1, \psi_2]$?

Comment: It was a typo, it should have been the expected value of the product of the two functions $\psi_1$ and $psi_2$, evaluated at a permutation

Comment: Is the intended addition and scalar multiplication point-wise addition and scalar multiplication of functions? If so, then the functions $\psi_{i,j}$ do not span the space of functions from $S_n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. A natural basis would consist of Kronecker deltas of permutations. (In other words, $\delta_{\sigma} (\tau) = 1$ if and only if $\sigma=\tau$.) Such Kronecker deltas would be orthogonal relative to your inner product, and you could make an orthonormal basis by scaling by $n!$. But maybe I'm misunderstanding the linear space you have in mind?